# How to sync gnome-calendar with an online calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar

I thought it was awesome that Ubuntu 16.04 shipped with gnome-calendar, but I noticed that holidays were not included.  I also noticed that there is an option to sync the calendar with an online one, how do I do this?  I don't know of any online calendars I could use.

[image: Add Calendar from Web]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can achieve that using the `gnome control center` in Ubuntu:

1. Type `gnome-control-center` into `dash`, settings will appear select that and select `online account`:

   [image: screenshot]
2. Then add your google account by clicking the plus sign at the bottom of the dialogue window that appears:

   [image: screenshot]
3. Then turn the calendar associated with that gmail account on, and this should sync it with Ubuntu Calendar.:

   [image: screenshot]
4. If you want more Calendars set it up in Calendar in google from the `settings options` **top right corner of calendar page**.
5. Google has changed how apps communicate with your google account so you have to setup your phone from [here](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/phone-sign-in/welcome) else you won't be able to add an account.

### Set up Google Account Calendar sync

1. Go to google calendar:

   [image: screenshot]
2. Get to `settings`, **top right of page**:

   [image: screenshot]
3. In ther click on the `Calendars tab`, **top left of page**:

   [image: screenshot]
4. In there click on `export calendars`:

   [image]
5. That will export your calendar in a `.ics` file format. Now Lets instruct `Calendar` to sync back in Ubuntu desktop.

### Instruct Calendar to sync with downloaded `.ics` file

1. Extract the downloaded `.ics` file
2. Start up `Calendar` and click on `Calendar Settings`
3. Form the dialogue box that appears select `from file`
4. Navigate to that extracted `.ics` file location, select it and **choose the one without the #[tag] at the start of the name**.
5. Back in Calendar select `synchronize` and make sure your internet is working and after a few minutes your synced calendars will appear.

Comment: M. Becerra will check the link as I just used it to setup mine. Right now on mobile will ASAP

Comment: @M.Becerra fixed the link, sorry about that...

Comment: Why do you need to import the *.ics file?  This seems like you are manually loading the existing google calendar events into gnome-calendar.  Shouldn't the sync process take care of "pulling" the existing calendar events?

Comment: Is this a manual process that has to be done everytime you want to ensure you have the same on both your computer and Google?  Or is it an actual sync operation, where this is a one-time setup procedure?

Comment: At this date, you just need to do the first part (Before "Set up Google Account Calendar sync") and restart, your calendar will sincronize inmmediately

Comment: I only needed the first part, and I also needed to change the "sync setting" in Google Calendar in order to show shared calendars in Gnome Calendar: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/-/issues/486

Answer (score 23):

To get all my Google calendars to sync, I had to go enable syncing them in a hidden Google sync settings page:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect

Then I had to disable Calendar for my Google account in Gnome Online Accounts settings, and re-enable it. After that all my calendars are synced.

[The same is actually needed for the Windows 10 Calendar](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_cal-winpc/how-to-sync-all-shared-google-calendars-to-windows/b3561cd6-9ec1-4499-8de6-55d9e2a54d7f), which is how I found it.

Comment: I had to do this for calendar delegated to me to appear.

Comment: I wish I could see your answer earlier!

Comment: My calendars also didnt show up until i uncheck / checked Calendar on the Google Account in Gnome Online Account settings.

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 20.04, following these steps should enable syncing Google services.

1. Go to Settings from the Dash.

   [image]
2. From Online Accounts(1) select Google(2).

   [image]
3. Give your Username for Google account.

   [image]
4. Give your Password for Google account.

   [image]
5. Allow access on your Google account.

   [image]
6. Select what services you want to be synced.

   [image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

I think ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 do not sync the Gnome Calendar with google calendar automatically.

I would suggest, since Evolution Mail treats the Gnome Contacts and Calendar, that you install Evolution with the important file evolution-data-server. Then you have to configure the google account within the Evolution Calendar. Some pictures of this operation were shown upstairs.

In the settings it is possible to choose even the important option "sync time" (the default 30 min is for me too much so I set it to 1 min) which is the time lapse between every synchronization. Finally you can see all Google events in the Gnome Calendar in the top bar.
After these operations you can remove Evolution Mail but not evolution-data-server which is necessary to do the sync.

Note: you have to do this operation if you want to use Thunderbird and not Evolution Mail. Thunderbird is the default application in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

For me, there was a bug with the gnome-calendar app where I could not click the "Add" button (the one in your screenshot), no matter what I entered.

I found a workaround by using the way the GOA (Gnome Online Accounts) works:

1. Download "Evolution" from the official repositories.
2. Add your online Calendar to Evolution. (Guides for adding several kinds of calendars to Evolution: [help.gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/calendar-using-several-calendars.html.en))
3. Verify that your appointments etc. are shown in the gnome-calendar app.
4. Uninstall Evolution. (If you do that, there is probably no way to reconfigure the calendar, so you could also just leave it as it is but still use the gnome-calendar app.)

In short, since Evolution also uses the GOA, just like gnome-calendar does, any calendar that you add there will also be added to gnome-calendar. The same should in theory apply for every other app that uses the GOA.

Regarding which calendar you should use, it depends. Holidays can be very different in different locations or even schools, so you need to find a source for yourself.

In general you have two options of adding holidays to gnome-calendar: Import an offline file (.ics) or the one I described above. Using one of the providers from the GOA Menu, like Google, Nextcloud or Microsoft Exchange is just a bit easier than importing a calendar from a custom provider.

More on this matter: [ctrl.blog](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/gnome-caldav)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed for me on Ubuntu 18.04 after I did the following (in terminal):

1. Stop calendar processes: `pkill -f calendar`.
2. Clean up cached files: `rm -rf ~/{.local/share,.cache}/evolution/calendar/`

Now start Gnome Calendar again as usual.

After this it downloaded all the updated calendar entries from my Google calendar. Also, the Synchronize button started working and the new entries from Google calendar started being visible in Gnome Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding your google account to your online accounts in the settings. Make sure to be connected to the internet so that your online account calendar will automatically sync with the local calendar.

In your case as you don't see the holidays,

1. Add holiday calendar from google

Go to https://calendar.google.com and login to access your calendar. On the left pane, you will see my calendars, if holidays is not ticked, tick that checkbox.

2. Selecting holidays that apply to you

If this option is not there, click the plus option on other calendars, and select browse calendars of interest, select the holidays that apply to you. After that save and reload the page.this will sync with your local calendar

Hope this helps,am using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

November 2022: this link shows how to get a secret address to share your calendar with Desktop applications. I confirm that it work to sync and **to see** (not to write) appointments on google-calendar. Again, do not expect to be able to create an appointment google-calendar and have it synced on the cloud.

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648#private&zippy=%2Csecret-address