# How do I sync non-google calendar with GNOME calendar?

Tags: calendar

When I insert link into gnome calendar it doesn't recognize it thus it doesn't let me to add it. How would you solve this?
[image]

Comment: If you have a google account google calendar works quite well for me but your question is as Kuffy says, subjective.

Comment: I'm n;ot an expert at formulating questions. I just copied the question from a similar topic I would be happy if the software that comes with ubuntu worked. Right now I can't import my calendar, on other os it worked just fine it's not a google calendar

Comment: how should I change my question? I mean the pre installed software didn't work for me so I ask around. Should I try to fix the software or .... ?

Comment: I checked the link it's not from a big compagny so I don't think I can add an account from my institution they just provide a link and you put it in the calendar that's how it worked b4 I switch to linux

Comment: I will try again tomorrow

Comment: alright I tried today and the calendar I need I could import it to google it shows up in gnome but it doesn't show event and all the other calendar show up it's such a mess. so the link above doesn't help me. and no I don't want to use google I want to import directly from my institution.

Comment: I'm talking about this https://askubuntu.com/q/911495/816190

Comment: I know how to import calendars I have done it before this software doesnt work.

Comment: Can you sync your non-goggle calendar to goggle first? Then it should work to gnome.

Comment: I synced my calendar with google then I synced my gnome-calendar with google but my calendar didn't appear.