# Error while starting gnome-control-center

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, software-center

I get the following error when I try to start `gnome-control-center` on Kubuntu 19.04:

```
$ gnome-control-center

(gnome-control-center:3239): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:12:56.364: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-control-center:3239): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:12:56.364: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:69:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
**
ERROR:../shell/cc-shell-model.c:458:cc_shell_model_set_panel_visibility: assertion failed: (valid)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Why do you want to start `gnome-control-center`  in Kubuntu? As far as I know, it is made for gnome desktop?

Comment: @Tejas Lotlikar good question. Basically I wanted to install google calender on Kubuntu. I found a tuto with gnome-control-center. That Is why.

Comment: Please post the link for the tutorial.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica https://askubuntu.com/q/911495/600715

Comment: The issue here is that I have many appointments on my calendar, but I cannot be notified if chrome is not running, So I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Forget about trying to get this gnome-core application to work while KDE is running. This is an application to configure the Gnome desktop, so it cannot do anything without Gnome Shell running.

Comment: If you're interested in using a solution more "native" to Kubuntu, see https://zren.github.io/kde/widget/eventcalendar/.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `locate gtk.css` and find where those files are:

Then you can comment out using command like:

```
sudo sed -i -E 's~^.*child-displacement-.*$~/* \0 */~g' /usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-3.20/gtk.css
```

For me, I also needed to run:

```
sudo sed -i -E 's~^.*-GtkScrolledWindow-scrollbars-within-bevel.*$~/* \0 */~g' /usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-3.20/gtk.css
```